# Jenkins to have docker build nodes with NFS shares mounted in the containers at run time

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to run a building job in Jenkins in docker nodes, but the build requires some data that is present on another NFS share. Hence I require this NFS share to be mounted on the Build Containers at the Job Run time. How to supply the NFS share information to the docker container.

I followed :

1. In the docker image created the directory to mount the NFS share
2. copied the fstab entries to be present in the container
3. RUN mount -a Fails when I do that

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

For now what i have done is I have used the Add Volume section under the container setting in Jenkins to Map the Volume. But I am still looking for a way to mount my NFS shares on the container created dynamically